# IndexError when trying to append with for loop

Tags: python, numpy, append, indices

This might be a foolish question,
I am trying to append values to a new empty array using a **for loop** and the values from a previously defined 3 dimensional array called `data_train_normalized`, which contains floats.

The objective is to end up with an array called `x`that has the value from the `data_train_normalized` in each value of the iteration. For example, `x[0]` should be the value `data_train_normalized[1,1,1]`

This sample code summarizes what I am trying to do:

```
x=np.array([])
for z in range(1,4):
  for x in range(1,4):
    for y in range(1,4):
      x = np.append(x,data_train_normalized[z][x][y])
```

And this throws:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-b0e7b7ab30e9> in <module>()
      3   for x in range(1,4):
      4     for y in range(1,4):
----> 5       x = np.append(x,data_train_normalized[z][x][y])
      6 #      print(data_train_normalized[z][x][y], z, x, y)

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: `np.append` is not a good function to use.  Stick with list append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices returned to that 3 dimensional array by x,y,z are **floats**! Whereas Python only supports **integer** and **Boolean** for indices of arrays (The error mentions this).

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type.
```

You can try converting x , y and z into int before passing them as indices simply using `x=int(x) , y = int(y)`

Also if you want to start the range from 1 only , then range(4) will do the work!
Refer to this for more info: [Python range ()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `x` parameter for both np array and `for` loop. Use a different parameter:

```
arr = np.array([])
for z in range(1,4):
  for x in range(1,4):
    for y in range(1,4):
      arr  = np.append(arr, data_train_normalized[z][x][y])
```

Comment: Thank you for making me realize the silly mistake, this time using the notation didn't help me at all.